# Netbeans - Simple Opening of Existing Projects and propagating of project settings

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8.1

I've a certain problem while using the newest Netbeans build on windows.

When I have a php project structure, where [name] indicates a folder with NB project inside, and {name} is a directory with composer/package/bower project inside:

- [proj1]

  - some dir
  - themes

    - {theme 1}

On `[proj1]` I have some ftp settings, that in Netbeans 8.0 propagated down all the way. In 8.1 when i try to upload files from `{theme 1}` i don't have that option anymore, the ftp select is disabled. It seems as NB finds `{theme 1}` as separate project, with no ftp settings.

Is there a way to propagate project settings from `[proj1]` ??